# How can i set proxy using selenium webdriver with browser HtmlunitDriver for Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, proxy

my name is Leo and i am a java bot developer, i am using Selenium webdriver and Browser HtmlUnitDriver headless, my question is like my title says: I know how to set proxy using FirefoxDriver but I don't wanna use UI browser because it's too slow to execute, so, searching in google and another page I don't found anything similar, if anyone know how open an Url with a proxy using HtmlUnitDriver, please help your answer will be useful for me, thanks.

I am using this for FirefoxDriver, i wanna do the same with HtmlUnitDriver.

```
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy("198.2.202.49:80")
         .setFtpProxy("198.2.202.49:80")
         .setSslProxy("198.2.202.49:80");
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer for my own question, i do the method that "@Raghav N" told me, Thanks a lot! :D (y)

I do this and work perfectly, and it can be tested because open www.find-ip.net and scrapped the actually proxy active, and its the same what i put.

Here the code Working, if you wanna test it, copy and paste in your proyect.
Note: with class proxy you need to "import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;"

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(); 
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("42.117.1.78:3128"); 
driver.setProxySettings(proxy);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.find-ip.net");
String ip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ipbox']/div[1]/div[2]")).getText(); // Copia el texto del actual ip
String pais = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ipbox']/div[2]/div[2]")).getText(); //Copia el texto del actual Pais del proxy
System.out.println("» Ip Ficticio: " + ip +" - Country: " + pais);
```

Output:

```
Ip: 42.117.1.78       -        Country: Viet Nam
```

If the page dont load maybe the proxy is down try with another.

I hope this will help you, bye! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with following code

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capabilities);
ArrayList<String> noProxyHosts = null;
driver.setHTTPProxy("198.2.202.49", 80, noProxyHosts);
```

Comment: thank you for reply, can i request u something? can you give me an basic code example opening a simple url using the code that you gave me? something that works only with copy and paste.

Comment: could you check below code?HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
  
  Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
  
  proxy.setHttpProxy("198.2.202.49:80");
  
  driver.setProxySettings(proxy);
  
  driver.get("http://google.com");

Comment: i am using this code to test in www.iplocation.com if ip that i am setting its the same like i gave it this is the code but do not Work yet :S

Comment: HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(); 
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy("173.234.8.5:80"); 
    driver.setProxySettings(proxy);
    driver.get("http://www.iplocation.net");
   String ip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='locator']/p[1]/b/font")).getText();
   String pais = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='geolocation']/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")).getText();
   System.out.println("Ip usada: " + ip +" Pais: "+ pais);